# mp3 files from samsung s6 edge to whatsapp

Tags: samsung, settings, default-applications

I have tried the attach icon on whatsapp to send a file of over 1 hour. I also tried to send it from audio in my files but i got an error message saying the file is over 16m...What do I do? Is there a settings change?

Answer (score 0):

In general, a lot of texting services, including whatsapp, have limits on the filesize of the files that you can send. These kinds of limits are also present in emailing attachments. The only way I can think to get around it is to split it into less than 16 minute chunks. Perhaps you might be able to compress it, but I am not sure if the 16 minutes will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Whether its a video, or a picture, you can’t exceed the 16 MB size limit. However, there are mods/hacks that help expending this limited mark. I found one [over here](http://wccftech.com/increasing-file-size-limit-whatsapp/). It works on rooted devices only.

This [post](http://technofizi.net/how-to-send-file-video-or-audio-more-than-16mb-using-whatsapp/) suggests to reduce the file size using apps (Available on the Play Store).

So decide which one fits to you.